# copyTo function is only working on second pass, with a hiccup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I Frankenstein's monster-ed this script probably 6-8 months or so ago.  When last I used it everything was working exactly as expected, but now it's broken.  I am trying to take a list of x-number of people, and either randomize the list or keep the list in the same order, then remove any empty cells, and then copy that information to a static column that I can use for later formuals.

What is currently happening, whether I try to randomize or not, is that on my first pass the sort and/or filter formulas work perfect, but the information does not copy, at all.  It should end up on the sheet `scriptsLocked` in column `C`.  Now after the first pass, if I then run the same option again right away (random or set), it will finally run the copyTo, but it leaves the first cell blank at `scriptsLocked C1`, the rest of the copied information is intact, but missing that first value.  Any help would be superbly awesome, thank you!!

Here is my entire script code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('4mans Menu')
    .addItem('Clear Sheet', 'clearSheet')
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Generate Champ Lobbies')
    .addItem('Random', 'champMenuRandom')
    .addItem('Set', 'champMenuSet'))
    .addToUi();
}

function clearSheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheet.getRange("scriptsLocked!A1:C32").clearContent();
    sheet.getRange("champLobby!B4:C35").clearContent();

    sheet.getRange("champData!D2:H97").clearContent();
    sheet.getRange("champData!M2:Q97").clearContent();
}

function champMenuRandom() {
  var sheetScriptsLocked = "scriptsLocked"  

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetScriptsLocked);

  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var cell2 = sheet.getRange("B1");
  cell.setFormula("=sort('champLobby'!B4:B35,arrayFormula(randbetween(sign(row('champLobby'!B4:B35)),1000000)),true)");
  cell2.setFormula("=filter('scriptsLocked'!A1:A32; len('scriptsLocked'!A1:A32))")

  sheet.getRange("B1:B32").copyTo(sheet.getRange("C1"), {contentsOnly:true});
}

function champMenuSet() {
  var sheetScriptsLocked = "scriptsLocked"

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetScriptsLocked);

  var cell = sheet.getRange("B1");
  cell.setFormula("=filter('champLobby'!B4:B35; len('champLobby'!B4:B35))");

  sheet.getRange("B1:B32").copyTo(sheet.getRange("C1"), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible it is taking a while to calculate the sort and filter cells after you call `setFormula`, so the values that `copyTo` is copying are blank the first time you run it. arrayFormulas in particular can take a while to calculate.

Try placing a `flush` between `setFormula` and `getRange`:

```
cell.setFormula("=sort('champLobby'!B4:B35,arrayFormula(randbetween(sign(row('champLobby'!B4:B35)),1000000)),true)");
cell2.setFormula("=filter('scriptsLocked'!A1:A32; len('scriptsLocked'!A1:A32))")

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
//If that doesn't work try sleep for 1 or more sec:
//Utilities.sleep(1 * 1000)

sheet.getRange("B1:B32").copyTo(sheet.getRange("C1"), {contentsOnly:true});
```